# View/Display PDF from retrofit response body android JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, retrofit

I am new to JAVA, android(JAVA) and retrofit. I am developing a android app that uses a web API to get the pdf and display/view(not download) on the screen. I was able to test the API in postman(POST request with empty body just with [ ]) and response is a pdf ( Content-type: application/pdf).
In android(JAVA), using retrofit, was able to call the api successfully, but from the response body , I am not able to get the PDF( Because not familiar with using streams(input/output). My purpose is to view the PDF not download.Please suggest. Please find the code:

WebAPI:

```
    public interface WebApiEndPoint {

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/pdf"})
@POST("MyEndpoint")
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
```

}

Retrofit Code:

```
 new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://localhost:5000/api/downlodeFile/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(WebApiEndPoint.class)
                    .downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(authToken)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //OK outpu
                            Log.i("PDF","Loading PDF");
                          
  //Not sure what code need to put here in order to retrieve the PDF and display it.                         
                            
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("PDF","Failed to load pdf");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: If your pdf file is on a server then you have to download it in order to view it on your device or to store it on your device.

Comment: Further it is unclear which app should display the pdf. Your app? In which pdf view component?

Comment: @blackapps ok, i understand that , I need to download the pdf in order to view it. PDF need to be viewed in my app.

Comment: Then why is there still 'not download' in your post? Viewed in your app ok. In which component? I asked that before.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Was able to display the pdf (without downloading) using the library : https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer . In this result, could find a method which will convert the retrofit response body to PDF on screen ( pdfView.fromStream(response.body().byteStream()).load(); )

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library to show PDF files.

in your case url is a PDF file then you can pass it to this library.

[Pdf-Viewer Github](https://github.com/afreakyelf/Pdf-Viewer)

This library can download and display the URL directly.
There is no need to use retrofit.

```
PdfViewerActivity.launchPdfFromUrl(       
            context,
            "pdf_url",        
            enableDownload = false 
    )
```

Comment: I checked the above link provided. It shows how to do it from assets(local) . I actually need to get the pdf from web api - from the response body after the retrofit call

Comment: @Learner This library can download and display the URL directly. Check the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Was able to get the result.